# Many fields in HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms, field

I have a form with about 150 fields, however the user can add more fields, reaching about 300 fields.
I'd like to know if exist a good way to put names and IDs to my fields, or i have to give each one a diferent name and ID. It's a hard job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html with only one name for input

```
 <form action="checkbox.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1">1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="2">2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="3">3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="4">4<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="5">5<br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

checkbox.php

```
$data = $_GET["data"]; //$data is an array with checked option
```

it works also for type text

```
<input type="text" name="text_data[1]"><br>
<input type="text" name="text_data[2]"><br>
<input type="text" name="text_data[3]"><br>
```

Comment: I take to put these numbers within textfield? ou can I put only <input type="text" name="text_data[]"> ?

Comment: no you do not need the numbers if the value of one input isnt related to the specific input field.

Answer (score 2):

if i understand in right, then you can use same name,id for group of same types of control (group of textbox,checkbox,etc...) and then access as array from javascript  or code behind ..

Comment: Take a look in my form: [link](http://osnysantos.com.br/form.gif). Each field I'm giving a diferent name and ID. Can I work with array?

Comment: here i think you can set name,id for each control as : "control-lable+control-type" and may be it satisfy your requirement.

Comment: array will work but i thinks its too difficult to identify which field to relates with each array elements ...

Comment: control-lable+control-type ? a diferent name for each field?